# How to semantically tag links to my Twitter and other profiles

Tags: semantic-web, schema.org, semantic-markup

I'd like to make the links to Twitter, Instagram, Goodreads, etc on my personal website to be tagged semantically, but I cannot find any reference on http://schema.org or elsewhere on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Google encourages the use of the [sameAs](https://schema.org/sameAs) property for this purpose.

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    …
    <a itemprop="sameAs" href="https://www.facebook.com/fburl">Facebook</a>
    <a itemprop="sameAs" href="https://www.twitter.com/twurl">Twitter</a>
</span>
```

In the specific case of Google, using this for Person or Organization encourages Google to use the information for that organisation's Knowledge Graph result. For more information, see:

- https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/social-profile-links